# Accessing SML tuples by Index Variable

Tags: tuples, sml

Question is simple.

How to access a tuple by using Index variable in SML?

```
val index = 5;
val tuple1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

val correctValue = #index tuple1 ??
```

I hope, somebody would be able to help out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: guess it's simple enough for you to google it out

Comment: I tried googling it. As I am a beginner, I couldn't able to figure out the suitable answer.!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't exist a function which takes an integer value and a tuple, and extracts that element from the tuple. There are of course the `#1`, `#2`, ... functions, but these do not take an integer argument. That is, the name of the "function" is `#5`, it is not the function `#` applied to the value `5`. As such, you cannot substitute the name `index` instead of the `5`.

If you don't know in advance at which place in the tuple the element you want will be at, you're probably using them in a way they're not intended to be used.

You might want a list of values, for which the `'a list` type is more natural. You can then access the `n`th element using `List.nth`.

Comment: you are actually not quite right about #id being a function. Se my updated post :)

Answer (score 9):

To clarify a bit, why you can't do that you need some more knowledge of what a tuple is in SML.

Tuples are actually represented as records in SML. Remember that records has the form `{id = expr, id = expr, ..., id = expr}` where each identifier is a label.

The difference of tuples and records is given away by the way you index elements in a tuple: #1, #2, ... `(1, "foo", 42.0)` is a derived form of (equivalent with) `{1 = 1, 2 = "foo", 3 = 42.0}`. This is perhaps better seen by the type that SML/NJ gives that record

```
- {1 = 1, 2 = "foo", 3 = 42.0};
val it = (1,"foo",42.0) : int * string * real
```

Note the type is not shown as a record type such as `{1: int, 2: string, 3: real}`. The tuple type is again a derived form of the record type.

Actually `#id` is not a function, and thus it can't be called with a variable as "argument". It is actually a derived form of (note the wildcard pattern row, in the record pattern match)

```
fn {id=var, ...} => var
```

So in conclusion, you won't be able to do what you wan't, since these derived forms (or syntactic sugar if you will) aren't dynamic in any ways.

Comment: Thanks Jesper! I've decided to use List for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

One way is as  Sebastian Paaske said to use lists. The drawback is that you need O(n) computations to access the nth element of a list. If you need to access an element in O(1) time, you may use arrays, which are in basic sml library. 
You can find ore about arrays at: 
http://sml-family.org/Basis/array.html